# Actionscript 3 - Incompatible Function & Duplicate function definition

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

enter code hereThe first two of my functions work, where i click on an easy button, and it goes to the easy level page, then i select my medium button and it goes to the medium page, but when i add in the difficult section part, it gets glitchy. and the two errors ( Incompatible Function & Duplicate function definition ) come up, any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Regards
Mosaic

```
//----easy option-----//  

stop();  

easy_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, easybutton); 

function easybutton (event:MouseEvent):void {

    gotoAndStop(3)

    }

    //---------medium option------// 

stop();  

medium_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mediumbutton); 

function mediumbutton (event:MouseEvent):void {

    gotoAndStop(4)

    }


    //-------difficult option--------//

stop();  

difficult_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, difficultbutton); 

function difficultbutton (event:MouseEvent):void {

    gotoAndStop(5)

    }

    //-------end option--------//
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Can you attach the FLA file?

Comment: the errors seem to occure on frame 5. Do not jumps in the timeline. The timeline is ment for animations... Better is to make a movieclip/Sprite for each level and add/remove it to/from stage, when you need it. Greetings

Comment: Subdan? will i mail you it so you can see, i can't seem to attach it on this.

Comment: you have given the same name to another function somewhere else, that's quite obvious.

Comment: There error means that you have the same name for two (or more) functions.  A timeline as a whole counts as a single scope. So if you have code on multiple frames of the same timeline, they all need unique var/function names.  eg: Frame 1 cannot have a function with the same name as a function on Frame 3 etc.